# how to run multiple updated statements in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, dynamic, parameters

I tried to run this script with the parameters in place but it keeps throwing syntax errors.Is there anything wrong with the syntax.Also what is the correct way to call this function.I require an output that tells me the update statement was executed successfully. I tried "select function_name(schema_name.TABLE_NAME);".Let me add that I am a beginner and am open to any kind of feedback. will also provide more details if necessary.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name (TABLE_NAME IN character varying)
RETURNS text AS $SQLQuery$
DECLARE SQLQuery text;
BEGIN

SQLQuery = 
' UPDATE '|| TABLE_NAME || ' SET column1=''0''
WHERE column1 is null;' ||

' UPDATE '|| TABLE_NAME || ' SET column2='value'
WHERE column2=''different value'';' ||

--multiple update statements later

Execute  SQLQuery;
Return SQLQuery;

END;
$SQLQuery$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Update:
this is the error i am getting when i call the test function

> ```
> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "schema_name"
> LINE 2: select test_function(schema_name.TABLE_NAME);
>                              ^
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "schema_name"
> SQL state: 42P01
> ```

it is reading the function as a table?
I have also received syntax errors saying 
EXECUTE column does not exist or that the function does not exist
even though i just declared it.

Comment: Providing the syntax errors (even if they make no sense to you) would be helpful.

The code you have provided is incomplete, which makes it difficult to even start suggesting improvements.

Comment: You have an extra single quote after the update value .

Comment: What do you mean by successful execution? No errors? Affected rows > 0?

Answer (score 0):

To use single quotes inside a siting constant, you must escape them by doubling them.

Instead of

```
' SET column1='0''
```

you'll have to write

```
' SET column1=''0'''
```

Comment: i made that change

Answer (score 0):

smth like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name (schema_name text,TABLE_NAME IN character varying)
RETURNS text AS $SQLQuery$
DECLARE 
  c int;
  rtn text :='';
BEGIN

execute format(' UPDATE %I.%I SET column1=''0'' WHERE column1 is null;',schema_name,TABLE_NAME);
get diagnostics c = row_count;
raise info '%', 'affected: '||c;
rtn = rtn + 'affected: '||c||chr(10);
--repeat above construct for multiple update statement
return rtn;
END;
$SQLQuery$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and advises. I'm novice like you, but I learned to follow several rules, that help me:

- with dynamic sql use `format` to avoid sql injection
- don't overcomplicate things (eg the functionality you are looking for is inside `UPDATE` statement already - check the output. If you want to check the resulting row use, `UPDATE ... RETURNING *` construct.
- practice is good, but reading concepts is precious.

In your POST `select function_name(schema_name.TABLE_NAME);` would not work, because you use **schema_name.TABLE_NAME** without quotes, but even if you put them, your function is vulnerable - what will happen if you run `select function_name(';drop sometable;--');`?..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass SQL Identifier, but your function takes string as parameter instead. You should change it to something like:
`select test_function('schema_name.TABLE_NAME');`

You can try that function below as base for whatever you are trying to do.

```
/* You need to split table and schema name
   or you might get errors when using names that aren't lower case.

   This: 'public.TEST1' would be translated to: "public.TEST1"
   that is different table from public.test1
*/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multi_update_stuff(schema_name varchar, table_name varchar)
/* We will return set of multiple columns. One possible method is to return table.
   First column shows executed query, second if it returned no errors (true)
*/
RETURNS TABLE(SQLQuery text, result boolean)
AS $body$
DECLARE
  /* Declare arroy of queries that we will iterate and execute later.
     We use format() to build query from template and fill it with values.
     %1$I can be described as "put first value here and treat it as object identifier"
     %3$L can be described as "put third value here and treat it as SQL literal"
  */
  SQLQueries text[] := array[
    /* First query */
    format('UPDATE %1$I.%2$I SET column1 = %3$L WHERE column1 is null;',
           schema_name, table_name, '0'),
    /* Second query */
    format('UPDATE %1$I.%2$I SET column2 = %3$L WHERE column2 = %4$L;',
           schema_name, table_name, 'value', 'different value'),
    /* Third query, to see error free result */
    'SELECT 1'];
BEGIN
  /* Iterate our array */
  FOREACH SQLQuery IN ARRAY SQLQueries
  LOOP
    /* Start transaction block */
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE SQLQuery;
      result := true;
    /* Catch error if any */
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN others THEN
        result := false;
    END;
    /* Return row with whatever is assigned to variables listed in RETURNS.
       In this case SQLQuery was already assigned by FOREACH.
    */
    RETURN NEXT;
  END LOOP;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM multi_update_stuff('schema_name', 'TABLE_NAME')
```